# Netty file upload support via HTTP PUT method

Tags: java, netty

I am able to upload files via HTTP POST method using sample [HttpUploadServerHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadServerHandler.java) provided in Netty repository, but I would like to upload files via HTTP PUT instead. Is there a way to do this with Netty? There is a HttpPostRequestDecoder, but nothing equivalent for PUT as far as I can tell.

Comment: The githib link is dead, any chance can you fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HttpPostRequestDecoder handles POST,PUT and PATCH.

See [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpPostRequestDecoder.java#L166